# React Native, Component Exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5

there I'm relatively new to React Native. I'm trying to bind data from a local json server api. It was working fine when I was using class component for my EventList, but to integrate Navigation in App.js, I have changed it to function component, I don't seem to find the error. Can you explain what is this error and how to read it and understand it. I have added all the required code, Thanks

**App.js**

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator, StackView } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import EventList from "./EventList";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={EventList} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**EventList.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { FlatList, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import EventCard from "./EventCard";
import useState, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function EventList() {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const eventsArray = require("./db.json").events.map((event) => ({
    ...event,
    date: new Date(event.date),
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setEvents(
        eventsArray.map((e) => ({
          ...e,
          timer: Date.now(),
        }))
      );
    }, 1000);
  });

  return (
    <FlatList
      style={styles.list}
      data={events}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <EventCard event={item} />}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    />
  );
}
```

**db.json**

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "title": "Release RN course",
      "date": "2021-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
      "id": "05dafc66-bd91-43a0-a752-4dc40f039144"
    },
    {
      "title": "Demo a new app",
      "date": "2021-09-29T13:45:18.000Z",
      "id": "001c9b6d-00a9-465c-a2d3-afb7176a0a87"
    },
    {
      "title": "Go on holiday",
      "date": "2021-05-18T08:09:24.000Z",
      "id": "4cdbe78f-54df-4769-bf3b-02a930161ec5"
    },
    {
      "title": "Come back from holiday",
      "date": "2021-05-25T10:09:24.000Z",
      "id": "81066e94-5e2a-410a-986c-67dcc72d3a82"
    }
  ]
}
```

**EventCard.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import propTypes from "prop-types";
import { formatDate, getCountdownParts } from "./api";

export default class EventCard extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(this.props.event);
  }

  render() {
    const { days, hours, minutes, seconds } = getCountdownParts(
      this.state.date
    );

    return (
      <>
        <View>
          <View>
            <Text>{formatDate(this.state.date)}</Text>
            <Text>{this.state.title}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View>
          <View>
            <Text>{days}</Text>
            <Text>DAYS</Text>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text>{hours}</Text>
            <Text>HOURS</Text>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text>{minutes}</Text>
            <Text>MINUTES</Text>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text>{seconds}</Text>
            <Text>SECONDS</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**Error Reading**

```
TypeError: (0, _react.default) is not a function. (In '(0, _react.default)([])', '(0, _react.default)' is an instance of Object)

This error is located at:
    in EventList (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:623)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:616)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:498)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:74)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at App.js:13)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:12)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import useState, { useEffect } from "react";
```

is wrong, it should be -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
```

(and that combines your other import for react too, whereas you have two import lines at the min from "react", you only need the one)

The problem was you were importing React and aliasing it as `useState` and trying to use it like `useState`

Comment: Thanks. It is annoying when we make a stupid error and can't understand what error stack says.